# How to compile batch file with resources to exe and run it with its exe in C#?

Tags: c#

I have batch file and a folder with resources which include one executable file. This file in its turn uses these resources. I want to compile these resources (batch file, executable file and folder with resources) to one executable one. And after launch of this exe, my batch file inside should run with all the ensuing consequences.

I'd like to make it on C#. What should I begin with?

Comment: Why don't you just port the batch file to C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it exactly as stated then a reasonable approach would be to package all your resources into one zip file, embed it as a binary resource in your C# executable and have the executable [extract the resource](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Insert-any-binary-file-in-C-assembly-and-extract-it-at-runtime.aspx), [unzip the file](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) into a temporary directory and run it from there with `Process.Create`.

Comment: Thanks to your links I learnt new things I hadn't known before :) The day was lived for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon's answer is correct, but you can save yourself the coding entirely - that's what self extractors do. Check out the [WinZip Self Extractor](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagese.htm) for instance. It can do exactly what you want.